# Regex match with negative lookbehind, recursive pattern and negative lookahead

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I need to match this:

```
void function{ {  {  } }}
```

(function definition with balanced parenthesis)
but not this

```
static stTLookupTable RxTable[MAX]={
     
    {zero, one},{zero, one},{zero, one}};
```

I have tried to match with lookarounds with `(?<![[=])({((?>[^{}]+|(?R))*)})(?!;)`
But this matches {zero, one} in the variable declaration.

```
(?<![[=]){((?>[^{}]+|(?R))*)}[^;]$ doesn't work either.
```

In short, I need it to match function definition, but not the array declaration, assuming array initialization starts with `]=`.
Does anyone know how to match the function definition alone?

PS:  `{((?>[^{}]+|(?R))*)}` matches for balanced paranthesis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using PyPi `regex` module you can use

```py
import regex
text = """void function{ {  {  } }}   
static stTLookupTable RxTable[MAX]={
     
    {zero, one},{zero, one},{zero, one}};"""

print( [x.group(3) for x in regex.finditer(r'=\s*({(?>[^{}]+|(?1))*})(*SKIP)(*F)|({((?>[^{}]+|(?2))*)})', text)] )
# => [' {  {  } }']
```

See the [Python demo online](https://tio.run/##dU/BSsNAFLzvVwy5dDeGgvYosXgRxBZEexBiCrXd1KV137J5kdXtfntM6sWLj8fMwAy8ee6L38nO@t58OPIMr/c6CNaBUSLLsk8yOzSd3bIhGxExbkJKAETLGzZbtLxaEB06t9q8HTWewpmr5e1LXUaBcc4Yv7WnAmR1Kv7R6Xq4KYTzxrJEFaZ7T52TM4WGPAKM/W04bYzdGdZe@kn52uYyyvlNtY6pvjjJ@aVSeVIyf364fxzoTp0G/2/gagiopCYFxk9VDdX3Pw).

**Details**:

- `=\s*({(?>[^{}]+|(?1))*})(*SKIP)(*F)`:

  - `=` - a `=` char
  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `({(?>[^{}]+|(?1))*})` - a substring between balanced `{...}`
  - `(*SKIP)(*F)` - skips the match and restarts the search from the failure position
- `|` - or
- `({((?>[^{}]+|(?2))*)})` - Group 2 (technical, used for recursion):

  - `{((?>[^{}]+|(?2))*)}` - matches a `{...}` substring with balanced curly braces.

You need to return Group 3 from the matches.

Comment: This works, but I am getting it as a list. I actually want to replace the whole of {....} in the function def with ""(none). I have read from a file and stored it into a string.So, I want to be able to do this-                                  
 newstring = re.sub(pattern,")

Comment: @Aparnavenugopal `regex.sub(r'=\s*({(?>[^{}]+|(?1))*})(*SKIP)(*F)|({((?>[^{}]+|(?2))*)})', r'{none}', text)`, see [demo](https://tio.run/##dU/BCsIwDL33K8Iua@cQ1KNM8SKICqIehKkwtWpR29FlMu367bObFy@GR96DPJK89IVXJXtVJR6p0giaX3hBkBcIEXie91TiBOdcHlEoacBADQvWAgDJMEFxhAzXM6VuebpODncOy6LheD7a7CJDoK6mmzfXKgQluQ3/aNt3NwlJtZBIv8@0s/xAtR9ts4AaOhzEe2N3rZIOO4wFltFgNZ0sHI1Z6ea/hq4zMMv8ELRvZL3eyToaA1ZVHw).

Comment: Thank you, My mistake. You had already given the req info in your answer. But I did not get why it did not select the array initialization. Could you explain that if possible?

Comment: @Aparnavenugopal It did not select `RxTable[MAX]={...}` because the `={...}` text was matched and *skipped*: *`(*SKIP)(*F)` - skips the match and restarts the search from the failure position*

Comment: @ Wiktor StribiżewThank you for the explanation

Answer (score 2):

Using `(?R)` will recurse the whole pattern.

You can match *void function* or anything except the *[MAX]=* by matching word characters `\w+` or excluding allowed characters using `[^\s{}=,]+` and recurse the first subpattern `(?1)` using the PyPi regex module.

```
\w+(?: \w+)*({(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*})
```

**Explanation**

- `\w+(?: \w+)*` Match 1 or more words before the `{`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `{(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*}` Match the opening and closing curly's recursing the first sub pattern `(?1)`
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CvSS0T/1) | [Python demo](https://tio.run/##dY9Ba8MwDIXP868QPtlNKJTdOkLpfd1h9DBoO/BSpzVrbKMoWzfPvz2zk8JOk4T0Dh/iPf9FZ2fvh8G03iEB6pO@MuYVkUYLFSDffxZitYR05EyEJHevIR6K4kesFlLOouSMdYkU/MOZIzS9rck4GyBAnggxwt7m5uyOd6TI1NDR9tG5995v1dtFw/N1vLvN@uVQhYmEXH8yfGt0JTirY/mPjg9cMtYqqs86OxrDzBtjjyalEbdQJXSJahzCSD71bTkpMBa07VuNirS4vUk0KaRqIZfZBcvLo7EEEzE/oeu9kHIYfgE)

```
import regex

pattern = r"\w+(?: \w+)*({(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*})"

s = ("void function{ {  {  } }} \n\n\n"
    "static stTLookupTable RxTable[MAX]={\n"
    "     \n"
    "    {zero, one},{zero, one},{zero, one}};")

matches = regex.finditer(pattern, s)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):    
    print (match.group())
```

Output

```
void function{ {  {  } }}
```

---

To remove the `{...}` part:

```
import regex

pattern = r"(\w+(?: \w+))({(?:[^{}]++|(?2))*})"

s = ("void function{ {  {  } }} \n\n\n"
    "static stTLookupTable RxTable[MAX]={\n"
    "     \n"
    "    {zero, one},{zero, one},{zero, one}};")

print(regex.sub(pattern, r"\1", s))
```

See another [python demo](https://tio.run/##dY/BDgExEIbP@hSTnlrbSHAjIu5cxEFiV7IoGrSbdpal@uyri8TJzCT/d/gP8xV3PBrdr2t1KYxFsPIgK0KKHFFaDSOwlKW3hI0HEIO3OfORV2sfsiR5snGP83bglBAXu4xejdrBvtRbVEZ78NBcgBAg1c1S0qIOc1RbcLiYGnMqi0W@OUuYV@9czSbLbOQ/TWjmh/4hrRFgtAziD4ch5fF7qzSyt0rHlRv2tRFRJu1SAY7zun4B)